# Is this estimate $p_{n+1}^2 < p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot ... p_n$ true for prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory

I think to remember that if $p_1, ..., p_n$ are the first $n$ prime numbers, then
$$
  p_{n+1}^2 < p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot ... p_n
$$
for all $n \ge 4$, but I can't find a reference for it. If true, is it obvious (something like Euclid's trick) or more like Bertrand's postulate, etc.?

Comment: By Bertrand's postulate, $p_{n+1}<2p_n$, $p_n<2p_{n-1}$, thus $p_{n+1}^2<4p_n^2<8p_n p_{n-1}<p_1 p_2 p_3 p_{n-1} p_n$. This proves the result for $n\ge 5$.

Comment: For the fourth prime it is false: $\;7^2>2\cdot3\cdot5\;$ ...

Comment: @Don Antonio: Precisely for this it is assumed that $n\ge4$ in which case $p_{n+1}\gt 7$. Regards.

Comment: @CaveJohnson, alternatively, by BP and induction, $$p_{n+1}^2\lt(2p_n)^2=4p_n^2\lt p_n^3\lt(p_1p_2\cdots p_{n-1})p_n$$ where all we need is $p_n\gt4$ in the middle inequality. (The base case, of course, is $11^2\lt2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7$, with $n=4$.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

By Berty,
$p_{n+1} < 2p_n < 4p_{n-1} < 8p_{n-2}
...$
so 
$p_{n+1}^3 < 64p_{n}p_{n-1}p_{n-2}$
so
$p_{n+1}^2 < p_{n}p_{n-1}p_{ n-2}$
for
$p_{n+1} > 64$.